# Remote Desktop can not access LAN PC

Tags: windows, cisco, remote-desktop, windows-firewall, small-business

Have a Cisco VPN - I am able to login, and RDP to the SBS server.
When I try to access the LAN PC's they are not responding.
ireshark the connections on all the PCS at the time of the request, and I see the traffic Come to the LAN PC but the LAN PC never sends a response.

Bad Host Response
[image: Bad Response]

The Client PC is getting the response, but it is not sending back the response.

Correct Host Response
[image: Correct Response]

In this the response is being sent back. 
The firewalls are done by group policy.

Comment: Is the second wireshark capture from the SBS server? Or is there a PC on the network that does work?

Comment: Second is from the SBS Machine @Drifter104

Comment: There is no PC the VPN client can connect to other then the SBS Server - The PC on the LAN can access the Other PCs' fine. (Sorry missed the second part)

Comment: I am able to RDP to the VPN Client but not to the LAN Client as well

Comment: Check the LAN clients are using the same default gateway. If they have a different DG, they could be sending their packets somewhere else.